# Magento - iOS request service magento PHP Error

Tags: php, android, ios, magento

I have a service written by PHP interact with Magento system.
In PHP service, I make a function update price of a product. I request this url via GET method. Problem is I request this url in Android work ok, but iOS I got an error bellow:

```
string(391) "SQL ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND customer_id = 5303)' at line 1 SQL QUERY: SELECT `customerprices_prices`.* FROM `customerprices_prices` WHERE (product_id =  AND customer_id = 5303)
```

And here is PHP code:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(STORE_ILATIANO);
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($ipd);
$_product->setPrezzoconsgrossisti($wholesaler);
$_product->save(); <-- error when request in iOS(I am use AFNetworking library, Android work ok)
```

Any suggest this problem? I don't understand this problem occur in side iOS or Magento system.

Comment: no no, I don't make any query. I just call function in magento. If server side, why android work ok ?

Comment: i think you not pass the product_id

Comment: Example: I have url http://xxx/test.php?updateProduct&new_price=123. Request this url in Android with Loopj library is ok(also browser), but request this url in iOS is error. I check many time. It have product_id before save() function called.

Comment: How? How to get query when call $_product->save() function? I am not a Magento developer.

Comment: Yes, I see and understand that product_id is empty. But problem here is why ? When I call: $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($ipd); It return an object with everything, include product_id, price, name,... Then call $_product->setPrezzoconsgrossisti($wholesaler); to set new value for property PrezzoconsGrossisti in this object and save again. It only error when request in iOS :(